# How to calculate confidence for non standard bands?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

So I have a dataset :
`dt<-c(1106,1402, 827, 781,876, 1134,1014, 964, 848, 814, 772, 912, 923, 996, 569, 774, 1389, 900)`

lets assume a normal curve and running `t.test(dt)`
I get

> One Sample t-test
>
> data:  dt t = 19.057, df = 17, p-value = 6.579e-13 alternative
>   hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0 95 percent confidence
>   interval:
>     839.9344 1049.0656 sample estimates: mean of x 
>       944.5

Which is all standard fare for 95% confidence interval.

But what I'd like to find is what is the confidence in a specific range like from 850 to 900. Because I want to know the probability that the next datapoint will fall between 850 and 900.  Which package::function can do this?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a built-in function but it's not too too hard to compute using `pt()`, the cumulative distribution function for Student's t:

```
dd <- c(1106,1402, 827, 781,876, 1134,1014, 
        964, 848, 814, 772, 912, 923, 996, 569, 774, 1389, 900)
m <- mean(dd)
s <- sd(dd)
```

Now we (1) convert the desired range to "t statistic" scale (subtract mean and divide by sd) and (2) compute the cumulative probability of `x<lower_bound` and `x<upper_bound`

```
probs <- pt((c(850,900)-m)/s,df=length(dd)-1)
```

The probability of a value falling in the range is the difference of these two values.

```
diff(probs)  ## 0.08805229
```

Comment: I haven't done it, but you could double-check by putting in the 95% confidence intervals quoted above as limits and making sure the answer from this procedure is 0.95 ...

Comment: Well, some part of that code has an issue. Putting in the CI.95 numbers of 839.9344 and 1049.0656 and the diff(probs) comes up with .374 not .95. So that code doesn't work.  Did you make a typo there somewhere?

Comment: actually, I was wrong -- that range/CI is the estimate for the *mean* (so it's based on the standard error, not the standard deviation: `diff(pt((r95-m)/(s/sqrt(18)),df=length(dd)-1))` is 0.95

Comment: Odd that 4 people voted up a wrong answer. LOL. So how to find the confidence of a custom range?